# No Private VLAN commands Cisco C3560 switch

Tags: cisco-catalyst, private-vlan

I'm studying Private VLAN on C3560 Cisco Switch hardware. When i enter the

```
(config-vlan)#
```

It doesn't contain the `private-vlan` command in the list of available commands. I turned the VTP mode to Transparent, VTP version = 1. VLAN 500 is created and active. IOS = 12.2(55)SE5. I followed this document in practiced [Catalyst 3560 Switch Software Configuration Guide, Release 12.2(55)SE]
Still don't know why. 
[image: ScreenShoot]
The version is here.
[image: Show version]

How can i get through this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Event when i change VTP version = 3, it still didn't have the command.

Comment: Have you actually tried to enter the command, and is it rejected? Sometimes the 'list of commands' is not correct, so first of all I would like to confirm if it's just a cosmetic issue or if the command is really missing.

Comment: And, what image version / feature set are you running, can you include "show version" output in your post please.

Comment: Can you add the output of "show version" and "show license"

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this _is_ a Catalyst 3560 with that IOS version? For instance, a Nexus would need the `switch(config)# feature private-vlan` global command run before the Private VLAN commands are available.

Comment: @hertitu I entered the full-command private-vlan and result is Invalid input

Comment: As JohnK wrote, can you also add `show license` please?

Comment: Thank you guys, my switch is running LANBASE license, just found out and let you know. At least I should have an ipbase license to run private-vlan feature. Topic should be closed now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you guys, my switch is running LANBASE license, just found out and let you know. At least I should have an ipbase license to run private-vlan feature. Topic should be closed now. Thanks again.